# How to find memory leak from ASPX app having a DLL

Tags: facebook, memory-leaks, asp.net

Any tips How to figure out where is memory leak in my Facebook app,  its ASPX using Facebook toolkit DLL and I am afraid the bug may be in that CS library.

The problem is that after one week uptime, server is running out of memory and needs to be rebooted, there are quite many users and I cannot run debugger on this "production server", so I would need to simulate somehow use on my local PC.

Comment: Switch to the real thing "java", dotnet is a poor copy.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a dump (sorry for my phrasing) of the application.

There are some tips on [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) on how to do it, and how to read the dump files.

Then you can see which objects are allocated, and which ones prevent garbage collecting.